# something in docker-compose.yml does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'?

Tags: powershell, docker-compose, yaml

```
--- 
db-server: 
  container_name: db-server
  environment: 
    - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Bruce1234
    - MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433
  image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest"
  networks: 
    - localdev
  ports: 
    - "1400:1433"
networks: 
  localdev: 
    name: localdev
services: 
  main-api: 
    build: CryptoAPI/
    depends_on: 
      - db-server
    networks: 
      - localdev
    ports: 
      - "7000:80"
    restart: always
version: "3.8"
```

Any help is appreciated this is the precise error i get:

[Powershell error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IghH.png)

What is exactly wrong, I have googled everything.

Comment: Can you please check in Indentation is correct in docker-compose.yml

Comment: it may be an indentions issue in your yaml file.

Answer (score 5):

The question is getting old, but here is an answer for anyone else getting in the same situation.

The `db-server` is a container and therefore should be in the `services` block with the `main-api`, like this :

```
version: "3.8"
networks:
  localdev:
    name: localdev
services:
  main-api:
    build: CryptoAPI/
    depends_on:
      - db-server
    networks:
      - localdev
    ports:
      - "7000:80"
    restart: always
  db-server:
    container_name: db-server
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Bruce1234
      - MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest"
    networks:
      - localdev
    ports:
      - "1400:1433"
```

The order of the services doesn't matter, you just need the `depends_on` as you figured out.

Answer (score -1):

i upgrade my docker-compose version to 1.28.4. Then the problem is solved